# javascript loop com sleep

Tags: javascript

Como faria para que um ***for*** ou qualquer tipo de ***loop*** mostrasse o resultado respeitando o tempo de 1 segundo por exemplo entre uma iteração e outra?

Tentei assim e não deu certo:

```
for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
    setTimeout(function (){console.log('valor de i='+i); },1000);
}
```

O propósito desses intervalos se dá na seguinte situação:

```
dup.crtPdf=function(flag){    
    var array = $('#dup-jqxGrid02').jqxGrid('getrows');                          
    dup.arrayCrt = array.slice(0);                                               
    var tempo =0;
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){                                  
            var obj = new Object();                  
            switch (flag){
                case 1: obj.ireport = "/reports/samples/crt_frete_pago_completo"; break; // CASO FOR IGUAL A 1 - FRETE PAGO
                case 2: obj.ireport = "/reports/samples/crt_a_pagar_completo"; break;    // CASO FOR IGUAL A 1 - FRETE À PAGAR
            }            
            obj.parametros = new Array({"id" : dup.arrayCrt.pop().con_id });
            custom.ajax(obj,'registrar',"../relatorios/imprimir.php");
            window.open("../relatorios/imprimir.php");                                          
    }               
};
```

Arquivo imprimir.php

```
    <?php    
    /* @author Maison K. Sakamoto
     * Data: 20/09/2013
     * @version 0
     * Arquivo Generico para imprimir quaisquer iport 
     * 
     * COMO USAR:
     * 1º FAZER UMA CHAMADA PARA A FUNÇÃO REGISTRO
     *      DEVERA FAZER UM POST VIA AJAX COM UM OBJETO CONTENDO DOIS PARAMETROS
     *      PARAMETRO 1 - STRING CONTENDO O PATH/NOME DO ARQUIVO.JRXML
     *      PARAMETRO 2 - ARRAY DE PARAMETROS NECESSÁRIOS PARA O JRXML FAZER A CONSULTA NO BANCO DE DADOS
     * 2º NO RETORNO DO AJAX(success) DEVERÁ SER FEITO UM "window.open()" CHAMANDO ESTE ARQUIVO
     */
    include_once 'server/Adl/Configuration.php';
    include_once 'server/Adl/Config/JasperServer.php';
    include_once 'server/Adl/Config/Parser.php';
    include_once 'server/Adl/Integration/RequestJasper.php';
    @session_start();                                                           //ABRE AS VARIAVEIS DE SESSÃO
    @$funcao = $_REQUEST['funcao'];                                             //PEGANDO O NOME DA FUNÇAO 
    is_string($funcao) ? call_user_func($funcao) : imprimir();                  //VERIFICA SE É UM REGISTRO OU IMPRESSÃO    
    function imprimir(){                                                        //FUNÇÃO IMPRIMIR        
        $obj = (object) unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);                          //PEGANDO DA SESSION E PARSE EM OBJECT                
        $jasper = new Adl\Integration\RequestJasper();                          //INSTANCIA DA API JASPERSERVER        
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');                                //CABEÇALHO SETANDO TIPO PDF
        echo $jasper->run($obj->ireport,'PDF',$obj->parametros[0]);             //EXECUÇÃO        
    }                                                                           //FIM DA FUNÇÃO IMPRIMIR
    function registrar(){                                                       //FUNCÃO REGISTRA OS PARAMETROS EM SESSÃO
        $_SESSION['obj'] = serialize($_REQUEST['obj']);                         //OBJETO COM ATRIBUTO "IREPORT" E "PARAMETROS"        
        echo json_encode(Array("info"=>"ok"));                                  //RETORNO DE CONFIRMAÇãO DO AJAX        
    }                                                                           //FIM DA FUNÇÃO REGISTRAR        
?>
```

Ou seja o `custom.ajax(obj,'registrar',"../relatorios/imprimir.php");` faz o registro na `$_SESSION` depois eu abro o arquivo imprimir.php com o `window.open("../relatorios/imprimir.php");` assim esse arquivo fica genérico podendo ser utilizado várias vezes mudando apenas os parametros no ajax, indicando qual **iReport** irá ser chamado

Comment: @DanielOmine n̶o̶ ̶m̶e̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶o̶ eu simplifiquei a pergunta justamente para poupar entendimento do propósito, que no meu caso seria disparar ajax para paginas php que faz uso de $_SESSION que essa não tinha **tempo** de gravar na session, então dei foco no problema que era disparar no javascript com intervalos, o propósito eu tenho certeza que não é duplicada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá você pode utilizar desta forma,

```
 var i = 0;
 var loop = setInterval(function(){ 
   console.log("valor de i="+i); 
   if(i == 10){
      clearInterval(loop);
   }
   i++;
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que eu precisava

Answer (score 5):

você pode combinar uma `closure` com um `setInterval`, para que ele funcione de forma similar à um `while`

```js
(function () {
  var indice = 0;
  var limite = 10;
  
  var interval = setInterval(function (){
    console.log('valor de indice=' + indice); 
    
    indice++;
    if (indice == limite) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  },1000);
})();
```

Segue uma alternativa inspirada no `Parallel.For` do `C#`, neste caso tenho uma function para gerenciar o `for`.

```js
var _for = function (fromInclusive, toExclusive, callback){
  var indice = fromInclusive
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    callback(indice);
    indice++;
    if (indice == toExclusive) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

_for(0, 10, function (i) {
  console.log("valor de i = " + i);
});
```

Comment: Muito interessante sua segunda solução, mostra que conhece a fundo  técnica em javascript parabens!

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, acredito que o maior problema neste caso não é o laço em si, mas controlar o escopo da variável `i`, apenas não entendi pq a resposta do #GuilhermeLopes ganhou mais up votes, se ele respondeu segundos depois ;D

Comment: eu votei na sua porque também vi sua resposta segundos antes, mas dei o aceite para estimular os novos aqui no SOPT, fica tranquilo que o up vote ou o aceite não quer dizer que sua resposta é inferior em nada viu!

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, quanto ao aceite, eu também faria o mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
    setTimeout(function (){console.log('valor de i='+i); },i*1000);
}
```

Comment: Opa isso já é um passo na frente, mas o valor de **i** ficou valendo 10 em todas as iterações ?

Answer (score 1):

Você já tem boas respostas de como fazer isso com o `setInterval` então não irei por esse lado.

Você pode criar uma função para aguardar o período desejado e chamar ela após cada loop, dessa forma:

```js
for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
   console.log('valor de i='+i); 
  aguarde(1000);
}

function aguarde(ms){
   var inicio = new Date().getTime();
   var fim = inicio;
   while(fim < inicio + ms) {
     fim = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

Fonte: [Javascript - Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414145/4843158)

Comment: É uma pessima ideia bloquear a thread para fazer um delay de 1s. lembre-se que javaScript normalmente executa apenas em uma thread e requer um modelo de desenvolvimento não bloqueante.

Comment: @TobyMosque Eu concordo que essa opção não "deva ser usada", por assim dizer. Eu apenas quis mostrar uma forma "diferente" das apresentadas. Acho que não expressei bem na resposta, falha minha.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa com **SetTimeout()** :

```js
var setTimeOut = (function(){
    var callback = null;
    var time = null;
    var iterate = null;

    if(!!iterate) iterate = 1;
    if(!!time) time = 1;

    var k = 1;
    var loop = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(typeof(callback) == 'function')
                callback(k);
            if(k < iterate){
                loop();
                k++;
            }
        }, time)
    };

    return function(c, t, i){
        callback = c;
        time = t;
        iterate = i;
        loop();
    }
})();
setTimeOut(function (i){console.log('valor de i='+i); },1000, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Vou explicar como fazer com `setTimeout` ao explicar por que o método do Rodrigo fez o `i` valer 10 todas as vezes.

`setTimeout` é uma chamada assíncrona. Isso significa que, no momento que o primeiro setTimeout disparou a função recebida, o laço já havia feito suas 10 iterações há muito tempo. A variável `i` recebida como parâmetro pela função é apenas uma referência, e essa referência já possui o valor 10, já que esse é o valor dela na última iteração do laço. A variável `i` continua viva enquanto uma função tiver uma referência a ela e, nesse caso, várias funções ainda têm.

**Como resolver isso?**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    (function(indice) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Valor de i=" + indice)
        }, indice*1000)
    })(i); // uma chamada de função ocorre aqui, fixando o valor de indice para a função interna

}
```

Isso funciona porque, a cada iteração, uma função é de fato chamada e não apenas definida. O valor de parâmetros é avaliado no momento da *passagem* e não no momento da definição da função.